# Hide a Post everywhere except on redirect

Tags: redirect, login

I have many user contactmethods on my Profile page.  If the user has not completed them all, then every time they log in they are supposed to be redirected to a "Reminder" post.  But I want to hide this Post everywhere else.  I have a pre_get_posts function which performs this action:
`$query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 639 ) );`
which does a fine job of hiding Post number 639 everywhere.  The problem is that when I execute the login_redirect filter (which verifies that the required fields are finished), and it finds that the user's profile is incomplete, the redirect to the "Reminder" post results in a 404-Not Found error (because it has been excluded from WP_query - duh).

I understand that I'm causing my own problem, but I don't know how to get out of it.  How can I hide a Post everywhere except for when it is called specifically?

Comment: I think you need to change where your "hiding code" is executed. Can you change it so that it executes only after the `WP_Query` is initialised, so you can wrap it in an `if` that says "if the current page isn't 639, then hide 639"?

Comment: That would require a completely different approach.  I'm blocking access to this Post everywhere with this
`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ETSm_function' );
function ETSm_function($query) {
 $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 639 ) );
}`
My approach using post__not_in would have to be replaced entirely if I wanted to "execute only after the WP_Query is initialized," and I'm willing to do that, but I don't know what method to use instead. Might be better to set the $query argument conditionally,  I preceded it with `if (!$wp_query->is_singular() )` but that throws a fatal error.

Comment: Maybe if I look up the calling PHP program, which I believe is login.php, as a condition of setting the $query argument...??

Comment: I tried using PHP function like this:
` if(str_contains( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "/wp-login.php")) $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 639 ) );`
but I get another error - "undefined function".  How can a native PHP function be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

**********     I think I have it     ***********
you can't interrogate WP_query like I was trying to do.  You must work with the $query parameter's values like this:
`if( !$query->is_single() ) $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 639 ) ); }`
So if it's not a single Post, like in a list of Recent Posts or a list of posts in a Category, it won't show.  But if it IS a single post on display, then it appears.

Comment: FINAL (I hope) UPDATE.........
As it is, my answer will also hide the Post from the Admin>Posts list, which means you won't be able to edit it via the list.  To avoid this, use this line in your pre_get_post function:
` if( !$query->is_single() && !is_admin()) $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 639 ) );`
notice that both conditions are negative.